# Sending an authorised post request using RequestBuilder and HttpUriRequest

Tags: java, api, http

I want to send a post request which has a bearer authorization required in java. The body of the post request takes parameters of in the following json format in postman:

```
{
"name": "project-002",
"description": "Test number 2",
"users": [
    "ppallavalli@umass.edu"
]
}
```

I want to send a post request in the following way by which i executed my get request which needed authorization because authorization easier this way.

```
HttpUriRequest httpGet = RequestBuilder.get().setUri("https://sandbox.predera.com/aiq/api/projects/a-443018111").setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,authHeader).build();
```

In specific i want to send a post request using HttpUriRequest and RequestBuilder.post because authorization is easier in this case especially because the authorization required in my case is a Bearer token. Also, in the above request execution, auth header is string i have already initialized to a Bearer authorization token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RequestBuilder.post()` to build a POST request with a `StringEntity` to pass your JSON String. Rest of the headers including Authorization etc. should remain same.

```
String url = "https://sandbox.predera.com/aiq/api/projects/a-443018111";
String jsonString = "{...}";
HttpUriRequest httpPost = RequestBuilder.post(url).setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json").addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader).setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString)).build();
...
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! should my request parameters come in the variable jsonString though? if so how do i exactly write the above body in the string?

Comment: @abzd You can either use a library to convert your JSON object to a String or have to escape the double quotes in your string. For Example: `String jsonString = "{\"name\": \"project-002\", ...";`